# post categories - how to show only categories with a specific parent id

Tags: posts, categories

I'm trying to display a post category, I have two categories with two different parents.

I want to show only one of the category according to the parent category.
This is the code that I am using at the moment to get the posts category.

```
$categories = get_the_category();
echo '<span class="parentCat">more from ';
foreach ( $categories as $category ) {
    echo '<a href="/#'. $category->slug .'"><strong>' .$category->cat_name. '</strong></a>';
}
echo '</span>';
```

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

You can use `get_categories` if you know parent category id.

```
$categories = get_categories( array(
    'parent'  => $parent_id
) );
```